# Having trouble passing variable into a sub searching - getting runtime error '91'

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am trying to have my code run a search for the "Part Number" string in a cell, then copy that entire column. I have the code working when I run it without passing the string in and replacing the variable, however, when I try to do it with a string passed in as colName I get an error on the
'Set r = ActiveSheet.Range(c.Address) line.'

Here's the main function

```
Public Sub PreSE()

Dim SECopy As Workbook, BOM As Workbook: Set BOM = ActiveWorkbook
Dim fname As String, fPathFile As String
Dim BOMsheet As Worksheet: Set BOMsheet = ActiveSheet


fname = InputBox("Enter the file name to use, including file extension exactly as in the next window.")
Set SECopy = Workbooks.Add
fPathFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fname, "Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
SECopy.SaveAs fPathFile

Call FindSelCol("Part Number", BOM, SECopy, fname)
'Call FindSelCol("Manufacturer Part Number", BOM, fname)
'Call FindSelCol("Cage Code", BOM, fname)
'Call FindSelCol("Description", BOM, fname)

End Sub
```

And the sub for finding and selecting the column

```
Sub FindSelCol(colName As String, BOM As Workbook, SECopy As Workbook, UpCopy As String)

'Currently - selects column in first passed workbook with the header passed as a string
'WIP - trying to get it to copy that header into SECopy workbook

Dim c As Variant

BOM.Activate

With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set c = .find(colName, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Range(c.Address).Offset(1, 0).Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range(c, ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, c.Column).End(xlUp).Address).Copy
    End If
End With

'Paste into SECopy Book first sheet; Passed in, paste into first unoccupied column
If SECopy.Worksheets(1).Range("A1") = "" Then
SECopy.Workshets(1).Cells(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Else
SECopy.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If

End Sub
```

There is some extra code for something else I am trying to add so I will ask another question for that part.

Comment: Just a thought => `r` will be the same as what `c` is.  Also, `c` can still be `nothing`  If `activeSheet.Range(c.Address)` doesnt fail too, i'd say it's not getting hit.  Check for `nothing` before using `c` after the with

Comment: pass the worksheet in to your `FindSelCol` as an argument and don't use `ActiveSheet`. If you remove the parentheses you can remove `Call`

Comment: Thanks! I changed around a lot of stuff and made most of the sheets and book variables so I could pass them into the function and reference more generally so I can use this across other books. @SmileyFtW I don't understand what that means, what will that do and how will it help?

Comment: @ShawnMalone - Which part am I unclear on that I can provide more info on?

Comment: @SmileyFtW I don't understand the removing the parentheses and call part. I passed in the workbook as there is only ever one sheet in the other workbook so I wouldn't need to specify besides the sheet index. Is there a benefit to removing call and parentheses?

Comment: It makes the code cluttered and harder to read. The `Call` is what is driving the need to include the parentheses. Removing the `Call` allows you to remove the (unnecessary) parentheses.

Comment: You should get into the habit of fully qualifying your objects and avoid using default members (e.g. the `Value` property of the `Range` object). Doing that makes it perfectly clear what you are doing and avoids confusion. If you were to write `targetRange = sourceRange`, it's unclear. Are you wanting `targetRange` to be a range object with all of the properties of `sourceRange` (you'd be missing the `Set` keword) or are you wanting to assign the value of `sourceRange` to `targetRange`?

Comment: I think I get it. So there should be, as specific as possible, a qualifier in the command for what properties of whatever is being done to be clearer. Thank you!